# security of `JSON.parse()` in Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

Can I `JSON.parse` untrusted data and then validate its structure (e.g., map from strings to array of strings)? Or can bad stuff happen just from parsing `JSON` (like with `Marshal`, which is inherently unsafe against remote code execution)?

Comment: You fundamentally misunderstand what JSON is. There are no security concerns possible. JSON isn't code, you can't inject harmful values into it.

Comment: `JSON.parse` is safe. `JSON.load` is not. Always use the former unless you  really, really do need the specific behavior of the latter (which you won't).

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) does not evaluate anything, it parses json. What can go wrong? Nothing.

Comment: Well I think it depends what you put in the `JSON`, for example, `JSON.parse([1,2,3].to_json)` returns an array.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: JSON allows only a short list of data types (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)), therefore it is not possible to inject fancy and dangerous datatypes with JSON.

Comment: Technically `JSON.parse` *should* not evaluate anything, but there's been a few [massive "oops" moments in history](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/vulnerability/4835/ruby-on-rails-json-parser-remote-code-execution-vulnerability). It's generally okay to presume it won't execute code, but like any software, really nasty bugs happen.